# Cannot autostart unprivileged LXC containers on Debian 11 Bullseye

Tags: debian, lxc

`lxc-autostart` won't start unprivileged containers in Debian 11 Bullseye.

Start of unprivileged container in Debian 11 Bullseye was solved in this
[answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655898/cannot-start-unprivileged-lxc-containers-on-debian-11-bullseye) by using `lxc-unpriv-start` instead of `lxc-start` but I was not able to take advantage of this approach when using `lxc-autostart`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Basic solution

OK, so after few sleepless nights I ended up with a simple systemd unit file for each container. An example one may look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Linux container my-container-name
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/lxc-start -n my-container-name
ExecStop=/usr/bin/lxc-stop -n my-container-name
StandardOutput=journal
User=my-lxc-user
Group=my-lxc-user
Delegate=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `Delegate=yes` is simple follow up of recommendation posted [here](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/getting-started/) and also in the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655898/cannot-start-unprivileged-lxc-containers-on-debian-11-bullseye) I already linked above.

User lingering **not** required (mentioned [here](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/an-lxc-container-does-not-start-on-debian-11-currently-testing-version/10474/2)).

A sweet side-effect of this solution is that shutting down of the (unprivileged) containers no longer delays host shutdown (as described [here](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/unprivileged-container-delays-host-shutdown/6799)) because `/usr/bin/lxc-stop -n my-container-name` defined in `ExecStop` is used instead of sending signals.

### Tuning - Systemd templates

Thanks to [systemd template unit files](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/) it is possible to use single unif file for all containers. My final template unit file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Linux container %I
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/lxc-start -n %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/lxc-stop -n %i
StandardOutput=journal
User=lxc
Group=lxc
Delegate=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Since I named the file `lxc@.service` and placed it to `/etc/systemd/system/` I can control all my containers using `systemctl COMMAND lxc@my-container-name.service`

(Just beware that `lxc.service` is the original one, responsible for `lxc-autostart`)

Any improvements to the unit file etc. are welcome!! - as I'm no expert and I basically used the [official docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) and also [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640717/systemd-script-does-execstop-right-after-execstart).

### Tuning - Systemd user service

Another step forward would be to use Systemd user services so there's no need to act as root when new container is deployed.

The unit file would be slightly different:

```
[Unit]
Description=LXC container %I
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/lxc-start -n %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/lxc-stop -n %i
StandardOutput=journal
Delegate=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Since `multi-user.target` is [not available](https://serverfault.com/questions/739451/systemd-user-service-doesnt-autorun-on-user-login) for user services we must use `default.target` instead.

User lingering must be enabled this time so that the service starts on boot and not on user log in. Lingering can be enabled from root account using: `loginctl enable-linger <my-lxc-user>`

I saved the service file to `.config/systemd/user/lxc@.service` and enabled it using `systemctl --user enable lxc@my-container-name.service`

Comment: excellent! great success! could use a  update when the scripts/units become  obsolete after this is patched in the lxc-project. https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/3668

Answer (score 2):

I've got Debian 11.2 running the testing package of `lxc` (version 4.0.11-1). When using [mprudek's systemd unit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684449/86440) (`nano /etc/systemd/system/lxc@.service`), I always got this error with and without lingering sessions enabled:

```
$ journalctl -f -u lxc@container1
Mär 10 20:32:42 vm-debian systemd[1]: lxc@container1.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mär 10 20:32:42 vm-debian lxc-unpriv-start[485]: Can't start an unprivileged container on a pure CGroups v2 host without a systemd user session running.
Mär 10 20:32:42 vm-debian lxc-unpriv-start[485]: If you are trying to get a non-interactive user to have unprivileged containers running, you need to
Mär 10 20:32:42 vm-debian lxc-unpriv-start[485]: enable lingering sessions for that user, via loginctl enable-linger lxcuser as root.
Mär 10 20:32:42 vm-debian systemd[1]: lxc@container1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mär 10 20:32:42 vm-debian systemd[1]: Failed to start LXC container container1.
```

I've updated the systemd unit as follows and it works like a charm. My unprivileged LXC containers run under the `lxcuser` account.

```
[Unit]
Description=LXC container %I
Requires=systemd-user-sessions.service
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
Wants=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/lxc-unpriv-start -n %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/lxc-stop -n %i
StandardOutput=journal
User=lxcuser
Group=lxcuser
Delegate=yes
RemainAfterExit=1
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
SuccessExitStatus=0
RestartForceExitStatus=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
$ loginctl enable-linger lxcuser
$ systemctl disable lxc@container1
$ systemctl stop lxc@container1
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl enable lxc@container1
$ systemctl start lxc@container1
```